# CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation returns no record zone IDs

Tags: cloudkit, ckfetchrecordchangesopera

I'm using CloudKit in my app and have begun by following the best practises in the WWDC video"CloudKit Best Practises"

The first thing to do is to check for changes which I do like so,

```
let changesOperation = CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: databaseChangeToken)
changesOperation.fetchAllChanges = true
changesOperation.recordZoneWithIDChangedBlock = { self.recordZoneWithIDChanged($0) }
changesOperation.recordZoneWithIDWasDeletedBlock = { self.recordZoneWithIDWasDeleted($0) }
changesOperation.changeTokenUpdatedBlock = { self.changeTokenUpdate($0) }
changesOperation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock = { self.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletion($0, isMoreComing: $1, error: $2) }

privateDatabase.add(changesOperation)
```

There are records in the private database that I am setting up the fetch for, but I only ever get the `changeTokenUpdatedBlock` and the `fetchDatabaseChangesCompletion`.

Am I right in saying I should expect to see `recordZoneWithIDChangedBlock` being hit when I run this operation and my private database's default zone to be passed in to this block?

It means when I call my `fetchDatabaseChangesCompletion`, there's nothing to fetch because the array of record zone IDs is empty: (note, `error` is nil)

```
fileprivate func fetchDatabaseChangesCompletion(_ newToken: CKServerChangeToken?, isMoreComing: Bool, error: Error?)
{
    if let error = error
    {
        //  Handle error

        return
    }

    let fetchZoneChangesOperation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: changedRecordZoneIDs,
                                                                      optionsByRecordZoneID: nil)
    fetchZoneChangesOperation.recordChangedBlock = { self.recordChanged($0) }
    fetchZoneChangesOperation.recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock = { self.recordWithIDWasDeleted($0, string: $1) }
    fetchZoneChangesOperation.recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock = { self.recordZoneFetchCompletion($0, newChangeToken: $1, clientSentChangeTokenData: $2, isMoreComing: $3, error: $4) }
    fetchZoneChangesOperation.completionBlock = { self.fetchRecordZoneChangesCompletion() }

    privateDatabase.add(fetchZoneChangesOperation)
}
```

Comment: Note, I'm currently passing in `nil` to `previousServerChangeToken` to fetch all changes...

Comment: Does this only give you the zone IDs that changed? Or is there a way to get the actual record IDs that changed?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum See the "Processing the Operation Results" section of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchrecordzonechangesoperation - It'll have the blocks that are called including ones for changed records

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem and it is due to `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation` and `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation` only working on custom zones. CloudKit really wants developers to compartmentalize data so they support more capabilities in custom zones.

> The disadvantage of using the default zone for storing records is that it does not have any special capabilities. You cannot save a group of records to iCloud atomically in the default zone. Similarly, you cannot use a CKFetchRecordChangesOperation object on records in the default zone.

[CKRecordZone `default()` Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckrecordzone/1514919-default)

`CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` was deprecated in iOS 10 and replaced with `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation`.